Non-rectangular widgets on QVideoWidget
I'm writing a media viewer application based on QMediaPlayer. Let's say I want to put some non-rectangular widgets on video (it can be some playback controls, video info, etc.), but for some reason Qt fills areas outside of widget contour with background color of QMainWindow (blue areas on the screenshot below).

As you can see, Qt actually draws both widgets as rectangles and tries to imitate transparency by filling those areas with background color of parent widget (which is QMainWindow).
Are there any ways to draw non-rectangular widgets without these areas?

Below is simplificated code for my app. There are two different circle widgets: green circle is a widget with overriden paintEvent(); red circle is a QFrame with border-radius set.
MRE
mainwindow.h:
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QFrame>

class Player;
class Overlay;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow() = default;

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;

private:
    Player* player;

    Overlay* overlayWidget;
    QFrame* overlayFrame;
};

class Player : public QVideoWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Player(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    ~Player() = default;

private:
    QMediaPlayer* mediaPlayer;
};

class Overlay : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Overlay(QWidget* parent);
    ~Overlay() = default;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

mainwindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QPainter>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");

    player = new Player(this);
    player->show();

    overlayWidget = new Overlay(this);

    overlayFrame = new QFrame(this);
    overlayFrame->setStyleSheet("background-color: red; border-radius: 50px;");

    resize(500, 300);
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    player->setGeometry(0, 0, width(), height());
    overlayWidget->setGeometry(100, height() / 2 - 50, 100, 100);
    overlayFrame->setGeometry(300, height() / 2 - 50, 100, 100);
}

Player::Player(QWidget* parent) : QVideoWidget(parent), mediaPlayer(new QMediaPlayer())
{
    mediaPlayer->setVideoOutput(this);
    // put your mediafile here
    mediaPlayer->setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl("qrc:/media.mp4")));
    mediaPlayer->play();
}

Overlay::Overlay(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void Overlay::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter p(this);

    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    p.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0));
    p.drawEllipse(0, 0, 100, 100);
}


I have already tried:

Use setMask() in Overlay::resizeEvent() with ellipse as QRegion. It works but AFAIK there is no methods to use antialiasing in mask. Without antialiasing this widget simply looks awful.


Create both widgets as windows (with NULL as parent) with flag Qt::FramelessWindowHint and attribute Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground (something like Qt shaped clock example). It also works, but I want these widgets to be created as children for player window and not as separate windows.



Qt does not "tr[y] to imitate transparency by filling those areas with background", that's how video overlay works, but since the superimposed widgets obscure the area of the video widget, that part is not considered for the actual overlay. The safest and easiest way to achieve this is to use a QGraphicsView and QGraphicsVideoItem as video output. This would also allow to use antialiasing for any shape you want to add.

@musicamante Thank you for your answer! Are there any more universal ways to do it? For example, if I switch from QMediaPlayer to libVLC which integrates into QWidget's winId(), will I still be able to add non-rectangular overlay widgets over the video?

That would be even more complex and unreliable, and in some configurations it won't work at all. As said, the safest and easiest way is by using the graphics view framework.
